# Update a row with a specific id

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-update

`id` is the first column of my Sqlite table.

`row` is a list or tuple with the updated content, with the columns in the same order than in the database.

**How can I do an update command with:**

```
c.execute('update mytable set * = ? where id = ?', row)
```

**without hardcoding all the column names?** (I'm in prototyping phase, and this is often subject to change, that's why I don't want to hardcode the column names now).

- Obviously `* = ?` is probably incorrect, how to modify this?
- Also, having `where id = ?` *at the end of the query* should expect having `id` as the *last* element of `row`, however, it's the first element of `row` (because, still, `row` elements use the same column order as the database itself, and `id` is first column).

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the column names using the **table_info PRAGMA**. this will have the column names in order. You could then build the statement in parts and finally combine them.

e.g. for a table defined with :-

```
CREATE TABLE "DATA" ("idx" TEXT,"status" INTEGER,"unit_val" TEXT DEFAULT (null) );
```

Then

```
PRAGMA table_info (data);
```

returns :-

[image]

i.e. you want to extract the name column.

You may be interested in - [PRAGMA Statements](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html)

An alternative approach would be to extract the create sql from sqlite_master. However that would require more complex code to extract the column names.